# Calendar.getInstance() performance improvement with 'warm up' call?

Tags: java, calendar

I have noticed that if i call `Calendar.getInstance()` once, before i really need `Calendar` instance, performance on second call is improved.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    // this block of code performs faster if the above code is included
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

I am getting time since epoch from my server and initializing calendar with it. The calendar is then parsed for hours, minutes, second and milliseconds which are passed to native function that sets time.

What i have noticed is that clock difference between nodes is 2-5 milliseconds if i instantiate dummy calendar first, and 15-20 milliseconds if i don't.

I am measuring round trip time and packet travel time from node A to B, and vice versa.  I am sharing times tamps between nodes in request-response transactions and noticed that these time stamps are more off when there is no 'warm up'.

While it's probable that something is wrong with my measurements, i am consistently getting smaller values for travel times with the 'warm up' call.

I am looking at the source code of the `Calendar` and i don't see any explanation of this behavior.

Is there anything in calendar implementation that could affect performance of initialization with subsequent calls ?

```
Average from A to B: 21,4 

Average from A to B: 15,14 

Average from A to B: 14,84 

Average from A to B: 14,07
```

**With warm up call**

```
Average from A to B: 11,8 

Average from A to B: 4,77 

Average from A to B: 4,54 

Average from A to B: 4,4
```

**Update**

Single call to native functions in advance seems to also benefit from performance improvement as time difference went to 0.8 - 1 millisecond.

Comment: How did you measure the performance?

Comment: @Tunaki, updated answer. I really expect that something is wrong with my measurements but i am getting these results consistently.

Comment: Could be a factor of java internally classloading the Calendar class. Could be the Calendar class doing some static initialization. But why, if you're getting the time from the server, does this even matter?

Comment: I am getting time as a long value, which i somehow must parse and pass to native function that call SetSystemTime.

Comment: You might want to switch to System.currentTimeMillis or System.nanoTime if you are using the time to measure performance.

Comment: @DavidCullen i am measuring packet travel time from A to B by comparing their System.currentTimeMillis()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anything in calendar implementation that could affect performance of initialization with subsequent calls ?

Here's the code of `Calendar#getInstance()`:

```
public static Calendar getInstance()
{
    Calendar cal = createCalendar(TimeZone.getDefaultRef(), Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT));
    cal.sharedZone = true;
    return cal;
}
```

The code of `TimeZone#getDefaultRef()` is:

```
static TimeZone getDefaultRef() {
    TimeZone defaultZone = getDefaultInAppContext();
    if (defaultZone == null) {
        defaultZone = defaultTimeZone;
        if (defaultZone == null) {
            // Need to initialize the default time zone.
            defaultZone = setDefaultZone();
            assert defaultZone != null;
        }
    }
    // Don't clone here.
    return defaultZone;
}
```

and the one of `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)`:

```
public static Locale getDefault(Locale.Category category) {
    // do not synchronize this method - see 4071298
    // it's OK if more than one default locale happens to be created
    switch (category) {
    case DISPLAY:
        if (defaultDisplayLocale == null) {
            initDefault(category);
        }
        return defaultDisplayLocale;
    case FORMAT:
        if (defaultFormatLocale == null) {
            initDefault(category);
        }
        return defaultFormatLocale;
    default:
        assert false: "Unknown Category";
    }
    return getDefault();
}
```

Notice how both of these methods check for already initialized variables, e.g. the static variables `defaultTimeZone` and `defaultFormatLocale`. At least this is expected to improve the performance of the second invocation of `Calendar#getInstance()`.

Comment: Oh,  i see. Thank you. This really makes huge difference for my time synchronization.